# ScrollView in tabhost xml - android

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I want to be able to scroll within each screen in my android application. when you scroll I want the tab bar to scroll as well. My code works..However when you go to the screen with the tab bar, the tab bar is not visible..to see the tab bar you have to scroll up. Is there any way for the tab bar to be visible by default? thanks

My tab_host.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <TabWidget 
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean the TabWidget is not visible?  If that's the problem, on the FrameLayout, try setting the layout_height="0dp" and the layout_weight="1"

Comment: Also, for good practice, use "match_parent" not "fill_parent"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/c4K4xqmA did not work?  What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

A ViewPager is what you need and along with a sliding tab class.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/mPager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0px"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: Thanks..How do you use this?

Comment: Place that in xml. Give me your email, I'll attach the slider class. As well as sample code on how to use.